# What is the shortname of the "central" Git remote versus my remote?

Tags: git, version-control, naming-conventions

I seem to be getting myself confused between Git terminology versus conventions for [remote repo shortnames](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes#Showing-Your-Remotes). Here is the Git setup I have (I believe it's Git-flow-ish and similar to collaborating on Gitorious, GitHub, GitLab and similar sites):

1. My local repo [a]
2. My remote repo [b]
3. My colleague's local repo [c]
4. My colleague's remote repo [b]
5. "Central" remote repo - the one that we consider "final" by convention - used to merge/rebase/release/publish against - called "trunk" in SVN parlance - in our particular workflow there is only one branch here (called *master*) [b]
6. (bonus) My local repo on another machine [d]

[a] Stored on my machine
[b] Stored on common server
[c] Stored on colleague's machine
[d] Hypothetical, but included for completeness

What are the conventional shortnames of the remote repos? And how do I refer to my local repos? Up until now I've been using:

1. "my local repo"
2. `origin` (others would call it `d3vid` or whatever my username is)
3. "your local repo"
4. `alovelace` (of course, on her own machine, she would call it `origin`)
5. `upstream` (we all call it this)
6. "my other local repo"

Similarly, 5 could be the official remote repo of some project on GitHub, 2 my GitHub clone, 1 and 6 my local copies of that clone, 4 your GitHub clone and 3 your local copy of that clone.

However, the Git setting `upstream` seems to refer to "the destination remote repo+branch of a local branch". Similarly, `origin` seems to be a flexible term. I've obviously confused Git's "upstream" with the FLOSS concept of an "upstream project".

So, can anyone clarify - what names *should* I be giving the remote repos? I'm looking for a documented convention as close to "official" or "de facto" as possible - if it includes references to branch naming conventions, or other stuff I've glossed over, all the better.

Answer (score 0):

repository names on local as well as on remote will be same.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Official Documentation :
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started

Comment: the link helped me word the question better, thanks; I'm talking about remote shortnames, specifically upstream/origin/otheruser

Answer (score 0):

The [Git remote documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) does not consider the possibility of a "central" remote, presumably because it is DVCS-focused and workflow-agnostic.

By default, the first remote that you clone will be shortnamed `origin`.

There is no default shortname for successive remotes, they must set when added. (And can be changed later.)

Answer (score 0):

The [original Git Flow post](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) proposes the following shortname conventions:

- The "central" remote is shortnamed `origin`

  - (This remote contains the key Git Flow branches `master` and `develop`)
- Other remotes are named for their owner (user or team)

  - (Branches follow the Git Flow naming conventions `release-`, `feature-`, etc)

Thus, under Git Flow conventions `origin` does not refer to "my remote" but rather to "the central remote". "my remote" is shortnamed `myusername`.